# Can I Upload File with Metadata and Additional created Column Value in Document Library using Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, rest

I am trying to Upload file in Document Library with its meta-data like file name using REST API.

I have also created custom lookup column there in document library. now I also want add data in that lookup column.

How Can I achieve this. Is this possible to add this all in one request?

Any help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: You can not do that in one request. In the first request upload file and in the  2nd request update metadata.

Comment: @Atish, but it create 2 different version of file in document library

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps, one-by-one you can just use the "Upload" button on the ribbon or multiple upload button. This will keep metadata *if* it is already in the XML at the bottom of the file(open in notepad). If you want to just assign it then maybe the following links can help. I am currently trying to figure out how to do what I just described in powershell so let me know if you figure that out :)

How to set lookup fields and all others via powershell is in here. 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx

Here is a link to some arguably incomplete documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.aspx